# variable starting with 0 is being dropped by javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a form with an input field called ESN which users enters a digit number that usually start with 0 then a bunch of random numbers (basically like a serial number). After this esn, I have a checkbox that calls a javascript code

```
esn1 = 012345678998875
esn2 = 321446894441146
```

Here is my script:

```
//change picked up to yes
function applyPickedUp(row_id){  
var ESN = row_id; //phoneID 
$.ajax({
    url: "savepickedup.php",  
    type: "GET",
      //pass data like this 
    data: {ESN:ESN},    
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {  
    if (data=="1")
    $('#message').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>Record updated! Refresh to remove ESN from report.</div>" ); 
    } 

});  
//start the ajax            
}
```

My problem is that with ESNs starting with 0, the script drops the zero so its not updating my database. So for example esn 012345678998875 becomes 12345678998875 instead. As long as the ESN doesn't start with 0 my code works just fine. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Did you set your column's type as `varchar`?

Comment: How are you selecting row_id?

Comment: row_id value is the ESN `<input type="checkbox" name="pickedup" id="pickedup<?php echo $Page->esn->ListViewValue() ?>" value="Yes" onClick="applyPickedUp(<?php echo $Page->esn->ListViewValue() ?>)"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have two problems. First, if you declare a numeric variable in Javascript that starts with a leading `0`, you are potentially writing a octal number. Javascript will interpret it as octal if it doesn't contain any 8's or 9's. For example:

```
num = 012345678998875; // num is 12345678998875
num = 012345677777755; // num is 718048067565 (!)
```

Second, you can't get leading zeros to be encoded in a number anyway, and these numbers are long enough that if you added even one more digit, you would be in danger of overflowing Javascript's numeric range. Essentially, you need to treat these numbers as strings if they are primarily for identification and not for math purposes.

```
esn1 = "012345678998875";
```

Comment: I have no problem with these values being treated as text since it is a text and no mathematical problems will be done on it. My db field is set as text as well. From my js code, how do I edit so that the value row_id will be treated as a string?

Comment: @ReneeCribe In your PHP, wrap escaped quotation marks around it, e.g. `\"$Page->esn->ListViewValue()\"`

Answer (score 3):

Try making the variables in javascript strings instead. Change this:

```
esn1 = 012345678998875
esn2 = 321446894441146
```

To this:

```
esn1 = "012345678998875";
esn2 = "321446894441146";
```